# Tizen Drawer Issue in Web Apps .

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, tizen

I am working on a Tizen app to display a calender with a list of holidays and it is working fine. I have 2 screens with a left slide menu. Now, the problem is that the main screen is sliding under the menu if the menu is opened and screen is pulled from right to left. I am not able to figure out why is it happening.
I tried to give z-index to both the divs but it was still not working.

So I tried working with the in built in tools to mitigate this issue , I tried the tizen in built drawer option as the left slide menu but there seems to be  some conflict b/w my calender js an the drawer js. {tau.js}

here is the link to the calender js library : http://www.vissit.com/jquery-event-calendar-plugin-english-version/

NOW, my only problem is the i am not able to load bit the js libs simultaneously. on loading tau.js , the calender is not loaded.

SOF is not allowing me to post screen shots! hope i am able to explain my self.

any suggestion would be a great help.

Comment: Is there anything in console when calendar is not loaded?
if jQuery is loaded TAU imitates jQueryMobile API so maybe there is a conflict here?